# error while building signed APK

Tags: java, android, gradle

I can run or build APK of my project but when I'm trying to build a signed APK , I get these errors ;

I can run or build APK of my project but when I'm trying to build a signed APK , I get these errors ;

I can run or build APK of my project but when I'm trying to build a signed APK , I get these errors ;

I can run or build APK of my project but when I'm trying to build a signed APK , I get these errors ;

I can run or build APK of my project but when I'm trying to build a signed APK , I get these errors ;

I can run or build APK of my project but when I'm trying to build a signed APK , I get these errors ;

I can run or build APK of my project but when I'm trying to build a signed APK , I get these errors ;

I can run or build APK of my project but when I'm trying to build a signed APK , I get these errors ;

[screenshot of my errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw3yp.png)

I downloaded the files and replaced them with the difalt ones but didn't change anything ;

here is me build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}









repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'C:\\Users\\T\\Desktop\\abbyy-rtr-sdk-1.0.8.26.Android_2\\libs\\'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abbyy.rtr.sample.datacapture"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            // In your application you might want to copy all files in the standard assets folder
            assets.srcDirs += ['../../assets', '../../License', "../../scenarios-datacapture/assets"]
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'abbyy-rtr-sdk-1.0', ext: 'aar')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'

//    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta1'

//پوشه
    dependencies {
        compile 'co.ronash.android:pushe-base:1.4.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    }

// پوشه
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Post `build.gradle` app level file

Comment: how ? (i'm new in stack overflow)

Comment: Means add `build.gradle` file's code in your question using `edit` tab below question.

Comment: see updated answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to fixed it by adding:

lintOptions {

checkReleaseBuilds false

}

in build.gradle.

Now clean and build & installRelease works.

Comment: i did it and got errors : {Could not find method lintOptions() for arguments [build_eny0svbx6g55ozlwfpoha5j53$_run_closure4@472d284a] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.}

Answer (score 0):

Add `mavenCentral();` inside build.gradle (*App level*)

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral();
    jcenter()
}
}
```

and this `buildscript` code below `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i did it but nothing changed

Comment: post your build.gradle file